# Maven-Ant task is not copying anything

Tags: maven

I've got this Ant task that I execute at the deploy phase.

The output of Maven says that the Ant plugin is ran, but it doesn't do anything. Even the  is not done.

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>deploy</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <target name="Pushing to builds repository">
                        <copy todir="${basedir}/builds/" verbose="true">
                            <fileset dir="target/">
                                <include name="**/*.jar"/>  <!--${project.exe_finalname}.jar-->
                            </fileset>
                        </copy>
                        <echo>from target/ to ${basedir}/builds/</echo>   
                    </target>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

And maven's output is:

```
--- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ zploger ---
Skipping artifact deployment

--- maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (default) @ zploger ---
Executing tasks
Executed tasks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade your antrun plugin. I suggest to set `<version>3.0.0</version>`.